# How to remove two subdirectories from a URL via mod_rewrite?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a URL to remove two subdirectories and display the page in the root directory instead. This the code I use in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is my complete .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^page$ subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is the .htaccess in the first subddirectory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectoryone/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectoryone/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, when I open the URL www.mysite.com/page it displays an error 404. By the way: I am using Wordpress, installed in the first subdirectory – does that make any difference?

Also, it works when I only remove the first of the two subdirectories.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it makes a huge difference with WP install. WP hijacks every URL and tries to route it through index.php and that's most likely why you're getting the 404. Let us see your whole htaccess rules.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I added the complete code.

Comment: Do you have wordpress installed in both directories? If not, why have the Wp rules in both. It should be just in htaccess in the directory it's installed in. The will help for starts.

Comment: Alright, I removed it. I updated the the post. Thanks, again.

Comment: Ok so you have WP installed in a sub folder correct? Ok nevermnind, that's what it looks like.

Comment: Yes, WP is installed in the first subfolder.

Comment: The page in this link `subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page` is it a real file, a folder or what?

Comment: I guess I'm confused because you want to use `http://yoursite.com/page` and redirect to a page that is located `subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page`? Is that correct?

Comment: I want to rewrite the URL. The page is located at `http://mysite.com/subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page` but I want to be able to access it from the URL `http://mysite.com/page`. The page is a generated by Wordpress – hence not a real file, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually solve this problem but I finally found a workaround for what I want to do:

I installed the WordPress plugin 'Permalink Editor' which allows me to change the URL from

```
www.mysite.com/subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/subdirectoryone/page
```

Then, I added the following to the .htaccess in the root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ subdirectoryone/page [NC,QSA,L]
```

This way, I can access the page www.mysite.com/subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page from the URL www.mysite.com/page.

*Lesson learned: In WordPress, always look for a plugin before asking stupid questions.*

Answer (score 0):

It's probably got something to do with the way wordpress is extracting the path info and request URI information. If you request `/page` and even if the rewritten request gets to wordpress, wordpress may be looking at the request URI and see "`/page`" and assume that's a 404.

I'm sure there's some wordpress specific way of handling these sort of things, but if you have mod_proxy loaded, you can try adding a `P` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page [NC,QSA,L,P]
```

So that the request `/subdirectoryone/subdirectorytwo/page` goes through the entire request handling process in it's own request.